# How much noise is necessary to disrupt the connection of a comlink?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

The core rulebook says how noise influences matrix actions that have a dicepool but not about actions that do not use a dicepool. E.g. when I want to make a call how much noise is necessary to block the call? Would noise from distance be taken into consideration especially with a long distance call?

Comment: +1 what @gatherer818 said, should post it as an answer. Looking at the noise numbers, I will opt for the double rating version, since simple rating would become quickly down (dense foliage gives 1 noise for 5 meters)

Comment: @CorvenDallas I think you are absolutely right. If you would go by RAW than that would imho mean that a metalink could not work in downtown Seatle which sounds silly to me. Thank you for your input I will probably create a similar house rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it.

Page 421 in my PDF of the Corebook:

> If there is a Noise Rating from a situation that is greater than the item’s Device Rating, not including distance, the item temporarily loses its wireless functionality (see Noise, p. 230)

So yeah, your super-cheap R1 Commlink loses connection if you're just 5 meters into the bush, while an R6 Commlink holds steady two-and-a-half stories underground.

Comment: Great answer, but I think I would use double rating in my games, is a bit non-sense so low power. Great job finding the right RAW answer @gatherer818!